# jQuery: Make event happen only once on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to track how people are scrolling on my site using jQuery. At the moment, my code log messages to the console every time a person scrolls through 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% of the page's content.

As you can see I'm creating four separate functions for each stage, and preventing the events from firing all over again with the off()-function. However, to me this way of doing it seems excessive. Is there any better way of doing this without having to create as many functions?

The code below works just fine (as far as I can see). I'm just wondering if there are any better solution for what I'm doing?

PS. I'm a complete beginner, so please take this into consideration when responding :)

```js
$(function(){


var totalHeight = $('footer').offset().top - $(window).height();
var twentyFive = Math.round(totalHeight/4);
var fifty = Math.round(totalHeight/2);
var seventyFive = Math.round(totalHeight*0.75);


function twentyFiveFunction(){
 if( $(window).scrollTop() > twentyFive ){
  console.log("25 % scrolled!");
  $(window).off('scroll', twentyFiveFunction);
  $(window).on('scroll', fiftyFunction);

  }
 }

function fiftyFunction(){
 if( $(window).scrollTop() > fifty ){
  console.log("50 % scrolled!");
  $(window).off('scroll', fiftyFunction);
  $(window).on('scroll', seventyFiveFunction);
  }
 }


function seventyFiveFunction(){
 if( $(window).scrollTop() > seventyFive ){
  console.log("75 % scrolled!");
  $(window).off('scroll', seventyFiveFunction);
  $(window).on('scroll', scrollCompleteFunction);
  }
 }

function scrollCompleteFunction(){
 if( $(window).scrollTop() > totalHeight ){
  console.log("100 % scrolled!");
  $(window).off('scroll', scrollCompleteFunction);
  }
}


$(window).on('scroll', twentyFiveFunction);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery `one` function should simplify it a bit.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

You wouldn't have to use `off` each time.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'm not sure though what you mean. Sure, I could use the one-function, calling the function $(window).one('scroll', twentyFiveFunction). But as far as I can see, it would still requiere me to use the on and off-functions within my four containing functions as they will still run and log to the console more than once on scroll, no?

Comment: @wikipoz - You wouldn't have to use the off functions in the other containing functions because `one` only runs **once** and then 'turns off' automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
var max_scroll = 0;
var done = [false, false, false, false]
var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var perc = $(window).scrollTop() / height;
    if (perc <= max_scroll) return false;

    max_scroll = perc;
    var index = Math.floor(perc / 25) - 1;

    if (index >= 0 && !done[index]) {
        done[index] = true;
        console.log(((index + 1) * 25) + '% scrolled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding earlier. Anyhow, I came up with a good solution at the end. So if anyone's interested, here's what I came up with:

```js
var fired = [false, false, false, false];

 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
 var docHeight = Math.floor($(document).height());
 var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 500;
 for(i = 1; i < (fired.length + 1); i++){

 if( ( (docHeight * 0.25 * i) < scrollTop ) && fired[i-1] == false ){
  console.log(i/4*100 + "%!");
  fired[i-1] = true; }
  }
  });
```